# Function fill() for initialising array of arrays leads to unexpected results

Tags: arrays, julia

I initialise two arrays of arrays using fill():

```
A = fill(Vector{Float32}(zeros(Float32, 4)), 3);
B = fill(Vector{Float32}(ones(Float32, 4)), 3);
```

When I then try to add two of the subarrays `A[1]`, `B[1]` and store it in-place in the first array `A[1]` by
`A[1] .+= B[1]`
this results in all elements of `A` to be changed:

```
3-element Vector{MVector{4, Float32}}:
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

I found a workaround by initialising the arrays differently

```
A = Array{Vector{Float32},1}(undef, 3) 

for x in 1:3
    A[x] = zeros(Float32,4)
end

B = Array{Vector{Float32},1}(undef, 3) 

for x in 1:3
    B[x] = ones(Float32,4)
end
```

When I now do the same in-place addition, `A` is (as expected)

```
3-element Vector{Vector{Float32}}:
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I suspect, that I do not fully understand what `fill` does as it seems like that the broadcasting `.+=` acts on the whole array of arrays and not the indexed subarray.

1. Why is this the behaviour dependent on the initialisation?
2. Is there a way to get the same behaviour as in the workaround but using fill or any other one-line initialisation.

I am quite new to Julia, any help is appreciated. I work with the Julia version 1.9.2.

Comment: `?fill` gives *Every location of the returned array is set to (and is thus === to) the value that was passed; this means that if the value is itself modified, all elements of the filled array will reflect that modification because they're still that very value.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you do `A = fill(zeros(4), 3)`, you are taking the object `zeros(4)` and making an `Array` of that object with the dimensions specified.
It does *not* make `3` different `zeros(4)` and make an `Array` of them.**

In your loop version that is exactly what you do, you make a new `zeros(4)` each iteration and then slot it into the `Array`. To see the difference, imagine you had written this:

```
A = Vector{Vector{Float32}}(undef, 3)

x = zeros(Float32, 4)

for i in 1:3
    A[i] = x
end
```

Now you do your operation on the elements of `A`:

```
A[1] .+= ones(Float32, 4)
```

All the elements of `A` will change, because in fact there is really only one element, repeated 3 times:

```
julia> A
3-element Vector{Vector{Float32}}:
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Further, since `A = [x, x, x]` you will also see your modification of `A[1]` reflected in `x`:

```
julia> x
4-element Vector{Float32}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
```

**To do what you are trying to do in a concise way you could use list comprehensions:**

```
A = [zeros(4) for _ in 1:3]
B = [ones(4) for _ in 1:3]
A[1] .+= B[1]
```

*Usually* it would be even better to use a `Matrix` instead of a `Vector{Vector}`. In this case you would have avoided this particular trap with the `fill` method E.g.:

```
A = fill(0f0, 3, 4)
B = fill(1f0, 3, 4)
A[1, :] .+= B[1, :]
```

Would give you:

```
julia> A
3×4 Matrix{Float32}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```